# Can't get 1440x900 resolution with GRUB2 although vbeinfo says it's available

Tags: linux, grub, arch-linux

I'm trying to use GRUB2 in graphical mode with 1440x900 resolution, but the result is always garbled nonsense: the highest resolution I can get is 1280x800.

Word is from googling that long as vbeinfo lists a resolution, GRUB2 can use it. This doesn't seem to be true: vbeinfo says that 1440x900 is available but it doesn't work.

Testing it from the GRUB2 command line:

```
set gxfmode=1440x900
terminal_output gfxterm
# -> garbled nonsense

# back to trusty 640x480
terminal_output console
```

The graphics card is an Intel GM965.

Once linux boots the framebuffer switches to 1440x900.

**Added after epheminent's reply and various experiments**

`vbeinfo` lists two sets of modes.

The first set runs from 0x160 to 0x16b, with resolutions 768x480, 960x600, 1280x800 and 1440x900

Then - after a bunch of *text-only* modes - the second set, containing resolutions 1024x768, 800x600, and 640x480

The first set of modes aren't altered by `915resolution`. They all work except 1440x900.

The resolution of modes in the second set can be altered using the `915resolution` module / command available in GRUB2 >= 1.99.

```
# in /boot/grub/grub.cfg

insmod 915resolution

# 30, 32, 34 all work for me: all that varies is which modes are altered
915resolution 30 1440 900

# setting an impossible resolution changes the mode to "text-only"
# in my case 1280x1024 is not supported
915resolution 30 1280 1024
```

Clearly, 1440x900 should just work: adding it with `915resolution` is just a workaround.

Comment: This is an old, interesting question that just got bumped to the main page again.  In addition to ephemient's answer, there is a deleted one from Breakthrough about using gfxmode.  Your comment on the answer says it worked, but the edit to the questions says it didn't.  Can you update us on the status?  Ever get this solved?  If not, has it been overtaken by events or are you still looking for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [915resolution](http://www.nathancoulson.com/proj_grub2_915.shtml) module which enables GRUB 2 to enable Intel's non-standard resolutions.  It is based off of the userspace [915resolution](http://915resolution.mango-lang.org/) which adds VBE entries at runtime for these resolutions; they're not otherwise available from BIOS.

Comment: I have no problems using 1440x900 once linux has booted - sorry, I hadn't made that clear.

Comment: This time I read your answer properly - I'll try it, thanks

Comment: This alters stuff pre-boot so as to ensure a correct resolution for the booted linux console. In my case the linux console reslution is fine, I just want the highest possible pre-boot (grub) resolution, IMO 1440x900

Comment: @TomSW: Hmm.  So even if you load it first, it doesn't affect Grub's own VBE module (that gfxterm uses)?  I don't have any similar hardware so I can't test.  If that's the case, then I can't think of any solutions, sorry.

Comment: @ephemient: loading the module doesn't make a difference. I found a bug report that suggests the bios lists the correct modes but incorrectly programs them: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/701111. Whatever that means exactly.

Comment: 915resolution works!